# jQuery/javascript object passing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Up until this point, I haven't done much in javascript.  I recently started playing with jQuery and came across a tutorial on how to do [Edit in Place](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax) on a form.

The resulting code works perfectly if you hard-code the id of your container div in the function, but I'm having issues generalizing it for an id passed in to the function.

The code starts like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setClickable($('#editInPlace'));
});

function setClickable(target)
{
    $(target).click
    (
        function()
        {
            //Do some dom manipulation

            $('.buttonA').click(function() { saveChanges(this, false); });
            $('.buttonB').click(function() { saveChanges(this, true); });
        }
    )

    .mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("editable"); })
    .mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("editable"); });
}; //end of function setClickable

function saveChanges(obj, cancel)
{
    //Handle the save changes code

    //Reset the div
    $(obj).parent().after('<div id="editInPlace">' + t + '</div>').remove();

    //Call setClickable
    setClickable($('#editInPlace'));
}
```

The part I'm having issues with is the last call to `setClickable` inside of the `saveChanges` function.  If I hard-code the value of `$('#editInPlace')`, it works fine.  However, if I change the function signature to

```
function saveChanges(target, obj, cancel)
```

and pass in the target object from the setClickable method:

```
$('.buttonB').click(function() { saveChanges(target, this, true); });
```

calling

```
setClickable(target);
```

doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You might want to look at the Jeditable plugin, http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable or the Editable plugin, http://arashkarimzadeh.com/index.php/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
function setClickable(target)
{
    $(target).click
    (
```

to:

```
function setClickable(target)
{
    target.click
    (
```

You're passing in a wrapped set (also called a jQuery object) and then wrapped it in another wrapped set. The above fixes that. The alternate way to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setClickable('editInPlace');
});

function setClickable(id)
{
    $("#" + id).click
    (
```

You see what I'm getting at?

Answer (score 1):

You can always try using setClickable($(target)); to make sure you've got a jQuery object.